# Detecting characters and acting on them

Tags: python

```
    if what == "decode":    
    dog_input = input("What would you like to decode?")
    letternumber = len(dog_input)
    a=(dog_input)
    for i in range(a):    
        if dog_input[1] == "1":
            print("a")
        if dog_input[1] == "2":
            print("b")
        if dog_input[1] == "3":
            print("c")
        if dog_input[1] == "4":
            print("d")
        if dog_input[1] == "5":
            print("e")
        if dog_input[1] == "6":
            print("f")
        if dog_input[1] == "7":
            print("g")
        if dog_input[1] == "8":
            print("h")
        if dog_input[1] == "9":
            print("i")
        if dog_input[2] == "10":
            print("j")
        if dog_input[2] == "11":
            print("k")
        if dog_input[2] == "12":
            print("l")
        if dog_input[2] == "13":
            print("m")
        if dog_input[2] == "14":
            print("n")
        if dog_input[2] == "15":
            print("o")
        if dog_input[2] == "16":
            print("p")
        if dog_input[2] == "17":
            print("q")
        if dog_input[2] == "18":
            print("r")
        if dog_input[2] == "19":
            print("s")
        if dog_input[1] == "20":
            print("t")
        if dog_input[2] == "21":
            print("u")
        if dog_input[2] == "21":
            print("v")
        if dog_input[2] == "22":
            print("w")
        if dog_input[2] == "23":
            print("x")
        if dog_input[2] == "24":
            print("y")
        if dog_input[2] == "25":
            print("z")
        if dog_input[3] == "-64":
            print(" ")
```

This code does nothing- it will print a character a random three or four times. I would like a user to input numbers and get out letters, but it refuses to read. How do I get it to function? Also, is there a faster way of assigning numbers to letters?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation and shorten the code to show only the essential behaviour? Also if you give us an example of usage and the expected result, it's more likely for you to obtain help

Comment: Can you explain how you chose the indexes for each of your conditionals? Why does `if dog_input[2] == "19":` use the index `2`, but `if dog_input[1] == "20":` uses the index `1`?

Comment: Are the errors in your sequence deliberate? You have `"21"` twice, you are testing `dog_input[1]`, `dog_input[2]` and `dog_input[3]` seemingly randomly, and are ignoring the `i` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Maybe also provide an example of desired inputs and outputs

Comment: Also, indexing into your `dog_input` string will give *individual characters*, so any test for a two-character string (2 digits) will fail.

Comment: You can turn numbers into alpha by forcing char. For example print(char(97)) will print an 'a'

Comment: That you are looking for is a translation from integer number to letter. Lowercase letters have ASCII values starting at 97, so number -> lowercase letter is just a sum away, `chr(96 + integer_value)`. But you need to figure out how to translate your string input into numeric values, and how to keep subsequent numbers separate. Perhaps use spaces? `1 2 3` spelling `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary to store letters and their number :

```
dictionary = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26,' ':-64}
```

And then use Series to fetch key based on value which is in your case letternumber :

```
lookup_list = pd.Series(dictionary)
print(lookup_list[lookup_list.values == letternumber ].index)
answer = lookup_list[lookup_list.values == 19].index
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

```
for i in range(a) :
```

This will iterate the string or array letter by letter, so two digit inputs will not be detected. Example: input 12 will be taken as two seperate inputs 1 and 2.

**Solution :**

Take input as space seperated numbers and seperate it by considering space as delimeter. See the following snippet

```
dog_input_final = dog_input.split(" ")
```

The following code (only loop part) solves the issue as well it is a better way to assign number to character.

```
dog_input_final = dog_input.split(" ")
for i in dog_input_final:
    if(i == "-64"):
        print " "
    else :
        print chr(97+int(i))
```